# Django - Optimal way to sort models by boolean operation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's imagine I have this model and I would like to sort them by logical operation `n1 != n2`:

```
class Thing(Model):
    n1 = IntegerField()
    n2 = IntegerField()
    ...

    def is_different(self):
        return self.n1 != self.n2
```

If I sort them by `sorted` built-in function, I found that it does not return a Queryset, but a list:

```
things = Thing.objects.all()    
sorted_things = sorted(things, key=lambda x: x.is_different())
```

Now, if I use `annotate`

```
sorted_things = things.annotate(diff=(F('n1') != F('n2'))).order_by('diff')
```

it raises the following error: `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`.

I found a solution using `extra` queryset:

```
sorted_things = things.extra(select={'diff': 'n1!=n2'}).order_by('diff')
```

but following Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

> Use this method as a last resort
>
> This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future. Use it only if you cannot express your query using other queryset methods. If you do need to use it, please file a ticket using the QuerySet.extra keyword with your use case (please check the list of existing tickets first) so that we can enhance the QuerySet API to allow removing extra(). We are no longer improving or fixing bugs for this method.

Then, what is the optimal way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Conditional expressions

One option for it is to use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). They provide simple way of checking conditions and providing one of values depending on them. In your case it will look like:

```
sorted_things = things.annotate(diff=Case(When(n1=F('n2'), then=True), default=False, output_field=BooleanField())).order_by('diff')
```

## Q and ExpressionWrapper

There is another, a bit hacky way, to achieve that by combining usage of `Q` and `ExpressionWrapper`.

In django, `Q` is intended to be used inside `filter()`, `exclude()`, `Case` etc. but it simply creates condition that apparently can be used anywhere. It has only one drawback: it doesn't define what type is outputting (it's always boolean and django can assume that in every case when `Q` is intended to be used.

But there comes `ExpressionWrapper` that allows you to wrap any expression and define it's final output type. That way we can simply wrap `Q` expression (or more than one `Q` expresisons glued together using `&`, `|` and brackets) and define by hand what type it outputs.

**Be aware that this is undocumented, so this behavior may change in future, but I've checked it using django versions 1.8, 1.11 and 2.0 and it works fine**

Example:

```
sorted_things = things.annotate(diff=ExpressionWrapper(Q(n1=F('n2')), output_field=BooleanField())).order_by('diff')
```

Comment: Good one with the conditional expressions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can work around it using [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

class NotEqual(Func):
    arg_joiner = '<>'
    arity = 2
    function = ''

things = Thing.objects.annotate(diff=NotEqual(F('n1'), F('n2'))).order_by('diff')
```